# Importing enum which exits in node_modules giving error

Tags: angular

I have a angular application in which some enums were already created in @node_modules/@accounting/accounting-services/lib/enums folder...and those enums are also imported in many components.

But when I am trying to create a new enum in same path (@node_modules/@accounting/accounting-services/lib/enums) I am not able to import it in my component. Error says it has no exported member.

Newly created enum:-

```
file name : account-type.enum.d.ts
export declare enum AccountType{
   Savings : "Savings",
   Current : "Current"
}
```

Here is how I am trying to Import it in component:-

```
import { AccountType } from '@accounting/accounting-services'; //throws error
```

do I need to build the project again so that the node_module changes can be reflected?

Comment: You should not change files in `node_modules`. Any changes will be lost when you update dependencies or re-install the project.